# Why Firefox doesn't show Google Adwords?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm running Firefox 27.0.1 under Windows 8 64-bit. I have a webpage which I monetized with Google AdSense. When I enter to my web using Chrome, I can see the ads, they work well. But when entering with Firefox I just can't see them. The avast plug-in was blocking them, so I disabled it but there's something else. I checked out my installed add-ons and I have:

- Edit cookies
- Temper data
- View cookies
- avast! Online Security (disabled)

I have also installed IOBit Malware Fighter, so I disabled the "Ad Block" and "Browser protection" options, but nothing happens, I can't see the ads.

Is Firefox blocking Google Adsense ads natively or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [starting Firefox in safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: Oh thanks! That works! But I tried disabling all the add-ons before and it didn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! The avast! Online security add-on was disabled but I forgot to restart Firefox, so it was still blocking my ads! Thanks @and31415 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Add-ons

Disabled add-ons might not be truly disabled, even after restarting. By restarting Firefox in safe mode (**Help > Restart with Add-ons Disabled**) you can troubleshoot whether some add-on is to blame, and then remove it entirely if necessary.

## Further reading

- [Troubleshoot Firefox issues using Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)
- [Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems)